Check if the file from blob storage is in format of MMDDYYYY
I have a file from blob storage
newfile = Supervisor_08292024_095618.csv
I want to check if the date is in MMDDYYYY format.
I tried to create a pattern for correct filename pattern:
pattern1 =  r'Supervisor_[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{5}.parquet' 
if re.match(pattern1 , newfile ):
    file_valid = "True"

else:
    file_valid = "False"
    print(file_valid)

The result is True because file Supervisor_08292024_095618 met the pattern1 but when I try to change the MM and DD : Supervisor_29082024_095618 .parquet...the result is still True. Which is invalid because the second file is DDMMYYYY...

You can change the pattern like below to achieve your requirement.
import re

pattern = '^Supervisor_(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\d{4}_[0-9]{6}.parquet$'

filename = "Supervisor_08292024_095618.parquet"
    
if re.match(pattern, filename):
    file_valid = "True"
else:
    file_valid = "False"

print(file_valid)

Result when filename is in correct format:

Result when filename is not in desired format:


thank you so much, this resolved my issue. xoxo.

hi, i just wanna ask also if the last part [0-9]{6} can change into a pattern wherein can accept all kinds of characters (alphabet, numeric, special characters ex. ;',/@^&<>_+)

i tried this one:  pattern = '^Supervisor_(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\d{4}_^[\w.-]+$.parquet$'       i add ^[\w.-]+$.parquet$ to replace the last part, however wt the right filename patter, i got False output.

Give me sometime and I will try this from my end and will update the answer if needed.

Can you try this pattern ^Supervisor_(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\d{4}_[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()_+{}\[\]:;"''<>,.?/~`\\|-]{6}.parquet$ and let me know if its working or not?

hello @rakesh govindula, it's works perfectly fine. but i want to know if the last part can handle any length of characters. it could be 1 character or 2 or 3 characters. no exact length of characters.

i already know the answer. i just add * in the last part. thank u again.
